# Deciding Normal vs. Robust (Student-t) Bayesian Hierarchical Linear Regression

Tags: regression, bayesian, hierarchical-bayesian

From what I've researched, if your data contains a good number of reasonable outliers, robust regression is preferred in order to mitigate the effect of these outliers.  Also, I found that looking at plots of your response variable vs. your regressor should help give you a sense of the linearity of the relationship as well as the prevalence of outliers.   My question is, if you have a large number of regressors, how best should one go about justifying using robust hierarchical regression over normal hierarchical regression?  If say for one regressor, there are a large number of outliers, whereas for the others, the data are generally linear in their relationship, is that reason enough to go robust?  Thanks!